# Does angular have a render to string?

Tags: angularjs

I can create templates to display in the page, but what if I want to format some strings for other purposes like debugging, or sending simple messages to the server, or even plugging strings into an array that an ng-repeat would pick up on.

Is there an mechanism in angular similar to handlebars where I can compile a template and then render it to a string instead of into the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interpolate) for simple string interpolation, but due to the way control flow is tied to DOM elements via directives, you might be harder pressed to sensibly convert more elaborate structures to strings.

For instance:

```
var i = $interpolate('{{ some }} string {{ interpolation|capitalize }}');
var s = i({ some: 'Some', interpolation: 'thing' });
```

The challenge with using the richer control flow offered by directives is coming up with a reasonable way of generating a simple string (as opposed to HTML) from the result. Consider:

```
<div>
    <div ng-if="this">This thing</div>
    <div ng-if="that">That thing</div>
</div>
```

You could compile this using `$compile`, but at best you'll end up with something like this (assuming for example that `thisThing` is `true` and `thatThing` is `false`):

```
<div>
    <div ng-if="thisThing">This thing</div>
</div>
```

But that's not especially useful as a simple string (it is, of course, useful as DOM nodes -- which is the whole point of `$compile`). You might be able to use it as a template for some HTML, but you'll lose all of the various listeners and such that were attached during compilation when you convert it to a string. To get a simple string (`"This thing"`), you'd prefer interpolation:

```
`{{ thisThing ? 'This thing' : '' }}{{ thatThing ? 'That thing' : ''}}`
```

Comment: $interpolate is a big improvement for Crockford's supplant.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your looking for something like this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-App='app' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='textInput' />
    <button ng-click='comp()'>Compile</button>
    {{output}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app',[]).
controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService){
    $scope.comp = function(){
      $scope.output = myService.getCompiledStr($scope,$scope.textInput);  
    }
}).
service('myService',function($compile){
    this.getCompiledStr = function(scope,str){
        try{
            return $compile(str)(scope)[0].outerHTML;
        }
        catch(e){
            return null;    
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K65Hh/)

P.S. 
There may be better ways to do this using `$interpolate` as said in a different answer.